# Does PayPal REST API support adaptive payments?

Tags: paypal

I need to charge fee at every transaction made via PayPal so when user pays via my application i need to charge additional $1 to my PayPal account.

I know Adaptive payments in Classic API can do what i need. Is there a support for this in new REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API is a replacement to the Adaptive Payment API. However, if I understand that you're asking for the more complex payments like chained, parallel or split, then I believe they are scheduled to be supported by the REST API by early next year (2015).